# How do I compare two arrays and update the second array with the values from the first?

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

I have the following method that takes in an array of MyExampleClass and id. The current problem I am trying to solve is commented in the method.

```
        public void Update(MyExampleClass[] example, int id)
    {
        //get the current values
        var current = GetCurrentMyExampleClassValues(id);

        //Compare the example and current arrays

        //Update the OptedIn value for each item in the current array with the OptedIn value from the example array.

        //The result is our new updated array

        //Note that current array will always contain 3 items - Name1, Name2, Name3, 
        //but the example array can contain any combination of the 3.
        var newArray = PsuedoCodeDoStuff();

        var result = _myService.Update(newArray);
    }


        private MyExampleClass[] GetCurrentMyExampleClassValues(int id)
    {
        var current = new MyExampleClass[]
            {
                new MyExampleClass {Name =  "Name1", OptedIn = false },
                new MyExampleClass {Name =  "Name2", OptedIn = true },
                new MyExampleClass {Name =  "Name3", OptedIn = false }
            };

        return current;
    }
```

Comment: How would you like the array elements to be compared?  By value or by identity?

Comment: It is not clear to me if you want to update the passed in array (example) with the matching current optedIn value or viceversa

Comment: The current array will always have value Name1, Name2, Name3. I care about updating the OptedIn value for each of them based on what the user passes in the example array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you just need to loop over the current array. Each item in the current array is searched in the example array using Name as the key. If you find it then update.

```
foreach(MyExampleClass item in current)
{
    MyExampleClass exampleItem = example.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == item.Name);
    if(exampleItem != null)
        item.OptedIn = exampleItem.OptedIn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! That's what i need.